# Generate API usage jar (No actual code on any method)

Tags: java, maven, plugins, minecraft, auto-generate

Alright so I have a private plugin for my Minecraft network, which of course is coded in Java, I mention that it is a Minecraft plugin as this plugins do not have a main method, in case that is relevant.

What I want to **generate** is another project that contains every class, interface, constructor, method etc. of said project but emptied, the goal is to create this non-functional project to use it as a Maven dependency for my developers so they can work with it and it's documentation but not see the actual code of it to ensure that the code and it's sensitive information stays private, here is an example of I want to accomplish:

```
/**
 * Nice documentation goes here.
 */
public void a() {
    // A lot of important private code here.
}
```

Would be generated as

```
/**
 * Nice documentation goes here.
 */
public void a() {
    // Nothing here
}
```

Is there any way to do this besides creating the other project manually? Doing it manually is not really an option as this is a pretty big project and it's constantly updating, so it would generate a ton of work.

Comment: Why: `that the code and it's sensitive information stays private,` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise well, it's code related to player data and anti cheat functionality and Discord hooking, things of which I want to be the only person that can see, as this isn't a professional project I can't really tell devs to sign a NDA or something like that, they are helping me out, not working for me, so I can't really trust them all of the source code, I just want them to have access to use the API methods on their IDE, then upload the plugin to a test server that has the actual complete version of the API that works.

Comment: You know that java code can be decompiled?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, that is the reason why I want to generate a jar with methods only, not code on them, it would be just for development usage but it couldn't be executed nor decompiled to view the code as it wouldn't have the actual code on it. Because of the way the test server works (Remote linux server with different users), they wouldn't be able to download the full version of it as it is located on a folder their user doesn't have access to.